# Alterar tamanho coluna bootgrid

Tags: bootgrid

Estou precisando alterar o tamanho do `bootgrid`, já procurei em sua [documentação](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/) alguma forma de fazer isso e não encontrei nada parecido com o datatable, que permite mexer no width.

Sabem alguma forma de fazer isso?